# UITableView giving strange results

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Im sure this is going to be one of those things where someone points out something really obvious that Im doing but I cant for the life of me find the problem. Basically I have an array of strings and I am loading the text from the array into my uitableviewcells as and when it is needed. The problem comes when I begin to scroll and for some reason cell no.6 ie the 7th cell displays the text from array position 0 over the top of the text from array position 6 and when I scroll back up the text in cell 0 is behind or under (i cant quite tell) the text from array position 6!!?? I have no idea how I am doing this. Here is my code:

```
    NSMutableArray *titles1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"] atIndex:0];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] atIndex:1];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"] atIndex:2];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"] atIndex:3];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"] atIndex:4];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"] atIndex:5];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"6"] atIndex:6];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"] atIndex:7];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"8"] atIndex:8];
[titles1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"9"] atIndex:9];

self.secretTitles = titles1;
[titles1 release];
```

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    secretName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(10, 8, 100, 30))];
    secretName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    secretName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    secretName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    secretName.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0./255 green:0./255 blue:0./255. alpha:0.7];
    secretName.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0);
    secretName.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"row = %d", indexPath.row);
    secretName.text = [self.secretTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secretName];
}
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery. Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding new label to cell's content view each time cell is (re-)used so eventually you get several labels placed on top of each other. The correct approach is to add a label only once and then set text value to it:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        UILabel *secretName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(10, 8, 100, 30))];
        secretName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        secretName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        secretName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
        secretName.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0./255 green:0./255 blue:0./255. alpha:0.7];
        secretName.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0);
        secretName.tag = 100; // Arbitrary value that you can use later 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secretName];
        [secretName release]; // Do not forget to release the label!
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = [self.secretTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help..... Vladmir's solution has worked for me. I guess I need to read up on re-using cells!!.

Many thanks again

Jules

Answer (score 3):

Every time you configure the cell, you add a label as a subview. But the cell might be reused and have been configured before. You should either use the existing labels like `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` or add your label `secretName` when creating the cell somwhere just after alloc-and-init of a new cell. Then in `configureCell` you only set the text of the label.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a subview to each cell. The cell object is reused. Since the API doesn't know about your fiddling with the cell, anything you modify to it, *beside the standards*, is your responsibility.

You should use `cell.textLabel` or another *existing* member of `UITableViewCell` to show your data.

**OR:** do away with cell reusing alltogether, but that is not a smart thing to do performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the way UITableView re-uses cells. What's happening in your code is you're adding `secretName` to cells that already have it. Here's a quick rewrite of your code:

```
//we need a way to find the secretName UILabel in the cell's contentView

enum {
    kSecretNameTag = 255
};

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // we only need to set up the cell when we create it
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [self configureCell:cell];
    }
    // grab the secretName UILabel and set the text
    UILabel* secretName = [cell viewWithTag:kSecretNameTag];
    secretName.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"row = %d", indexPath.row);
    secretName.text = [self.secretTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    secretName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(10, 8, 100, 30))];
    secretName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    secretName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    secretName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    secretName.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0./255 green:0./255 blue:0./255. alpha:0.7];
    secretName.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0);
    secretName.tag = kSecretNameTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secretName];
}
```