# Cocoa - UITableViewController strange behaviour !

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm losing my mind on this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 

    UILabel *label;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30)];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

in the cells' labels, i see this numbers instead of the progression I am expecting (0,1,2,3,4...):

**0 1 2 0 4 1 2 0 4 1**

any idea where's the error? Seems I can't figure this out.

**EDIT**
resolved after putting the initialization of the label after the cell==nil{} block.(don't know why i put that there in the first place.)

Comment: I tried your code. Its working fine for me. Getting the numbers in order 0, 1, 2, 3....

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView giving strange results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354064/uitableview-giving-strange-results)

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform cell configuration **outside** of the `if`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30)];
    [cell addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}   

[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",indexPath.row]];
```

Oh - and you should release the label after adding it to avoid a memory leak :)

Comment: That would lead to another problem: a new label would be added each time the cell is reused.

Comment: What if I have to add a viewController over the cell? also label is out of scope at the setText part, and if you declare it before the IF block you get an exception

Comment: That code is invalid because `label` is not defined at the point where you send it `setText:`. Merely hoisting the `setText:` message out of the `if` block in the questioner's original code would not work either, because `label` would be uninitialized when `cell` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

UILabel *label;

if (cell == nil)

{

```
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
```

}

label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30)];

[cell addSubview:label];

[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",indexPath.row]];

[label release];

return cell;